Flutter drift for the web Unsupported operation: Unsupported invalid type InvalidType(<invalid>) (InvalidType)
I have set up my flutter web project with drift for data storage. However, when I try to run this following the documentation here, I get unsupported type errors. As a sample:
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf16.dart:68:22: Error: 'Pointer' isn't a type.
  static int _length(Pointer<Uint16> codeUnits) {
                     ^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf16.dart:93:33: Error: 'Allocator' isn't a type.
  Pointer<Utf16> toNativeUtf16({Allocator allocator = malloc}) {
                                ^^^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf16.dart:95:19: Error: 'Uint16' isn't a type.
    final Pointer<Uint16> result = allocator<Uint16>(units.length + 1);
                  ^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf16.dart:95:11: Error: 'Pointer' isn't a type.
    final Pointer<Uint16> result = allocator<Uint16>(units.length + 1);
          ^^^^^^^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/ffi-2.1.2/lib/src/utf16.dart:95:46: Error: 'Uint16' isn't a type.
    final Pointer<Uint16> result = allocator<Uint16>(units.length + 1);
                                             ^^^^^^

My database.dart file looks like the below:
import 'package:drift/drift.dart';

import 'dart:io';
import 'package:drift/native.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;

import 'package:sqlite3/sqlite3.dart';
import 'package:sqlite3_flutter_libs/sqlite3_flutter_libs.dart';

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:drift/wasm.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

part 'database.g.dart';

class TodoItems extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get title => text().withLength(min: 6, max: 32)();
  TextColumn get content => text().named('body')();
  IntColumn get category =>
      integer().nullable().references(TodoCategory, #id)();
  DateTimeColumn get createdAt => dateTime().nullable()();
}

class TodoCategory extends Table {
  IntColumn get id => integer().autoIncrement()();
  TextColumn get description => text()();
}

@DriftDatabase(tables: [TodoItems, TodoCategory])
class AppDatabase extends _$AppDatabase {
  AppDatabase() : super(_connect());

  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 1;
}


DatabaseConnection _connect() {
  return DatabaseConnection.delayed(Future(() async {
    final db = await WasmDatabase.open(
      databaseName: 'sample',
      sqlite3Uri: Uri.parse('sqlite3.wasm'),
      driftWorkerUri: Uri.parse('drift_worker.js'),
    );

    if (db.missingFeatures.isNotEmpty) {
      debugPrint('Using ${db.chosenImplementation} due to unsupported '
          'browser features: ${db.missingFeatures}');
    }

    return db.resolvedExecutor;
  }));
}


My folder structure in web has the files drift_worker.js and sqlite3.wasm from releases drift and sqlitelibs respectively.
My code will still throw all the errors outlined above.

The error happens because dart:ffi is a transitive import of package:drift/native.dart. That library cannot be imported on files meant to be compiled to the web.
The drift repository includes this example with a solution based on conditional imports. This involves four separate files, connection.dart, unsupported.dart, native.dart and web.dart. They look like this:
connection.dart
export 'unsupported.dart'
    if (dart.library.js) 'web.dart'
    if (dart.library.ffi) 'native.dart';

unsupported.dart
DatabaseConnection connect() {
  throw UnsupportedError('No database available on this platform!');
}

web.dart
DatabaseConnection connect() {
  return DatabaseConnection.delayed(Future(() async {
    final db = await WasmDatabase.open(
      databaseName: 'todo-app',
      sqlite3Uri: Uri.parse('sqlite3.wasm'),
      driftWorkerUri: Uri.parse('drift_worker.js'),
    );

    if (db.missingFeatures.isNotEmpty) {
      debugPrint('Using ${db.chosenImplementation} due to unsupported '
          'browser features: ${db.missingFeatures}');
    }

    return db.resolvedExecutor;
  }));
}

native.dart
DatabaseConnection connect() {
  return DatabaseConnection.delayed(Future(() async {
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      await applyWorkaroundToOpenSqlite3OnOldAndroidVersions();

      final cachebase = (await getTemporaryDirectory()).path;

      // We can't access /tmp on Android, which sqlite3 would try by default.
      // Explicitly tell it about the correct temporary directory.
      sqlite3.tempDirectory = cachebase;
    }

    return NativeDatabase.createBackgroundConnection(
      await databaseFile,
    );
  }));
}

For the database definition, import connection.dart and define the constructor like this: AppDatabase() : super(connect());. This will make the compiler look up the method for connect() either in native.dart or web.dart depending on which platform you're compiling to. The other file is never imported, avoiding the compilation error.
